# What word could describe the movement of a parked car inside which a couple is making out?

Tags: single-word-requests

"The car moved up and down", seems too simple. Maybe "sway", but it seems soft to me.

Comment: There’s always the old bumper sticker: *”If you see this car/van arockin’ don’t come aknockin’”*

Comment: Which aspect is more important? The fact that it's a ***car**?* (Maybe a small car containing a fat guy jiggling around listening to loud rock music.) Or the fact that people are ***making out*** in it? (In which case it could just as well be a creaky ***bed / mattress***, not a car.)

Comment: "WHEN police were called to a traffic jam in a remote area, they saw drivers gawking at a car rocking with a naked couple having sex inside." - New York Daily News

Comment: Do you mean having sex, because kissing (even if deep and passionate) will not typically move a car much: that requires significant back-and-forth motion.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly quirky term for a car rocking up and down is **jounce**. [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/101728), with two vehicle-appropriate examples:

> 1. intransitive. To move violently up and down, to fall heavily against something; to bump, bounce, jolt; to go along with a heavy jolting pace.
>
> 1967   C. O. Skinner Madame Sarah (new ed.) viii. 171   The train..swayed, rocked, jounced and hustled a couple of passengers from their seats.
>
> 1971   D. E. Westlake I gave at Office (1972) 55   The two trucks jouncing off along the narrow dirt road through the swamp

Jouncing is *rough*. Often, jouncing is caused by the motion of the vehicle against rougher roads, as the second half of the definition ("to go along...") and most examples show.

> Aggie gave a nod and watched the moped *jounce* down the country road toward town. (Connie Spittler, *[The Erotica Book Club for Nice Ladies](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Erotica_Book_Club_for_Nice_Ladies/zln7BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=jounce&pg=PA209&printsec=frontcover)*, 2015)

However, motion within the car can also cause it to jounce:

> He moaned again and tried to move. "Jane?" The car *jounced* with his movement and Jane felt her heart turn over with fear. (Amber Dean, *[Deadly Contact](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Deadly_Contact/e4lUAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=jounced)*, 1963)

Answer (score -1):

"*Undulate*" is a possibility; unlike "sway", it means up and down ([OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sway_1?q=sway)).

> [*undulate*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/undulate?q=undulate)
> [intransitive] (formal) to go or move gently up and down like waves
> ♦
> The countryside undulates pleasantly.

([ref. 1 "movement up and down or from side to side"](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Lily_of_the_Nile/WHI76fTP95YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22undulated%22&pg=PA243&printsec=frontcover)) Chryssa's naked body undulated as the whip came down on her skin, leaving hot red welts upon her back, and it seemed to me as if Iullus was watching with more than morbid fascination

([ref. 2  "movement up and down or from side to side"](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Killing_Her_Softly/YSmiCc_6Zj8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22undulated%22&pg=PT423&printsec=frontcover)) Falling into the rhythm he set, her body undulated with each strong thrust. The tension inside her built again, faster and faster as he increased the tempo. Knowing she was close to climaxing, she encouraged him with hot, erotic words

For a less gentle motion there is "*heave*".

> [*heave*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/heave_1?q=heave) [intransitive] to rise up and down with strong, regular movements
> ♦ The boat heaved beneath them.

There is also the verb "to bob".

> ([*bob*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bob_1?q=bob)) [intransitive, transitive] to move or make something move quickly up and down, especially in water
> ♦ an old cigarette packet bobbing along in the current
> bob up and down
> ♦ Tiny boats bobbed up and down in the harbour.

Apparently, despite the dictionary's definition, you can use "up and down" with these verbs. ([ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undulated+up+and+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cundulated%20up%20and%20down%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cundulated%20up%20and%20down%3B%2Cc0), [ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaved+up+and+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheaved%20up%20and%20down%3B%2Cc0)).

- The car undulated up and down.
- The car heaved up and down.

Comment: Rocking. Just rocking.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "to rock" means "to move gently  backwards and forwards or from side to side" ([OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rock_2)); that is not the direction that has been mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Please check Merriam-Webster also, @LPH. :)

Comment: 2a: _to cause to sway back and forth_
a boat rocked by the waves
b(1): _to cause to shake violently_
An earthquake rocked the town.

Comment: @user405662 The OP's question says "up and down", not "back and forth".

Comment: Yes, and that's implicit in the second meaning of the word.

Comment: *Undulate* is associated with waves and wave-like motions. Water, fleshly bodies, and fields of corn often undulate, as your examples show. A car *undulating* is a highly unusual thing to imagine. *Heave* is a much better answer, since your example involves a vehicle.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin  "Undulate" is  used a lot  for physical undulations that have nothing to with time (hills (up and down), roads (from side to side), …) : there is no motion. It is also used a lot as you say it: a motion of one or more dips and crests  (usually more than one) can be seen. I agree with you, it has to be rare as meaning moving up and down without bending, but in the case of those two examples of undulating bodies, is there so much of a wavy motion to be observed? Wouldn't we have to contend that the motion is  essentially rigid (up and down or otherwise)?

Comment: If it's moving *gently* they're not doing it right.

Comment: I also don't think *undulate* fits. I think of that as a swaying that progresses along something. A dancer doing the "inchworm" undulates.